# R ggplot when user upload files

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, graphics, upload

We can't select any X variable when I upload a files and there is no graphic either can you help please?

I want to create that when you upload a CSV files it can gives you a graphic and analyze it.

I am on R studio with shiny

```r
ui <- fluidPage(
    tabPanel("Upload File",
             titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
             sidebarLayout(
               sidebarPanel(
                 fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                           accept=c('.csv')),     
              ,
                 checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                 radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                              c(Comma=',',
                                Semicolon=';',
                                Tab='\t'),
                              ','),
                 
                 selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', "", selected = NULL),
                 selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "", selected = NULL)
                 
               ),
               mainPanel(
                 tableOutput('contents'),
                 plotOutput('MyPlot')
               )
             )
    )
  )
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) ` {
     output$files <- renderTable(input$upload$datapath)
     output$summary<-renderPrint(input$upload$datapath)
      myfiles <-read.csv(input$upload$datapath)
     
     observeEvent( myfiles   , {
      updateSelectInput(
        session, 
        inputId = 'xcol', 
        label = 'X Variable',
        choices = names(myfiles), 
        selected = names(myfiles),
      )
      
      updateSelectInput(
        session, 
        inputId = 'ycol', 
        label = 'Y Variable',
        choices = names(myfiles),
        selected = names(myfiles),
      )
    } )

    obersveEvent( output$plot<-renderPlot({req(r$myfiles)
      p<-ggplot(data=myfiles, aes(sym(input$xcol), sym(input$ycol , print(p)))) +geom_histogram()+theme_gray()
    })))

shinyApp(ui , server)
```

Comment: I edited your question to clean up some of the code, but I did not fix a glaring error: `obersveEvent` appears to be a typo. But that's probably your problem: never put `render*(.)` within an `observe`/`reactive` block, they are already reactive. Remove the `obersveEvent(`/`)` from around your `output$plot <- renderPlot(.)`, and perhaps it'll work.

Comment: Also, your `read.csv` is a one-time thing which will fail (since `input$upload$datapath` is not usable when it is first instantiated). It needs to be reactive. Likely `myfiles <- reactive(read.csv(...))`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is riddled with problems. I'll try to list everything I found, but it's possible I missed one or two.

- You define `fileInput('file1',...)` but use `input$upload$datapath`.
- Ditto, `plotOutput("MyPlot")` and `output$plot`.
- There are extra commas and parens throughout the code
- There is a `print(p)` in the middle of the aeshetics within `sym`.
- You call `read.csv(..)` outside of a reactive but your app needs it to be reactive, so ... make it `reactive`, and then replace `myfiles` with `myfiles()`.
- The `updateSelectInput` calls provide a full vector to `selected=`, it should be a length 1.
- `geom_histogram` can only have an `x` or a `y` aesthetic, not both.
- (Not a bug, but you define both `output$files` and `output$summary` but never use them.)

Here's a work shiny app that uses `geom_point`.

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabPanel(
    "Upload File",
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose CSV File',
                  accept=c('.csv')),
        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                     choices = c(Comma=',', Semicolon=';', Tab='\t'),
                     selected = ','),
        
        selectInput('xcol', 'X Variable', "", selected = NULL),
        selectInput('ycol', 'Y Variable', "", selected = NULL)
        
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput('contents'),
        plotOutput('MyPlot')
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # output$files <- renderTable(input$file1$datapath)
  # output$summary<-renderPrint(input$file1$datapath)
  myfiles <- reactive({
    req(input$file1$datapath, file.exists(input$file1$datapath))
    read.csv(input$file1$datapath)
  })
  
  observeEvent(myfiles(), {
    req(myfiles())
    nms <- colnames(myfiles())
    updateSelectInput(
      session, 
      inputId = 'xcol', 
      label = 'X Variable',
      choices = nms, selected = nms[1]
    )
    
    updateSelectInput(
      session, 
      inputId = 'ycol', 
      label = 'Y Variable',
      choices = nms, selected = nms[1]
    )
  })

  output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
    req(myfiles(), input$xcol, input$ycol)
    ggplot(data = myfiles(), mapping = aes_string(input$xcol, input$ycol)) +
      geom_point() +
      theme_gray()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui , server)
```